# Rails: Access grand-parent from child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have three models `Company` < `Deed` < `Subtransaction`, with `has_many` / `belongs_to` relationships and where  Company `has_many :subtransactions, through: :deeds`

So: `Subtransaction` references `deed_id` where `Deed` references `company_id`

In my rails console I can query `Company.first.subtransactions` succesfully. However, `Subtransaction.first.company` returns an error. If I add `belongs_to :company` to the model, it still returns `nil`.

How can I access the grand-parent `company` object from the child `Subtransaction` model?`

Comment: Access it through deed, obviously. `subtransaction.deed.company`

Comment: HI, Could you please add associations from all three models here?

Comment: yes, I was thinking myopically about calling directly, but `subtransaction.deed.company` works perfectly well. If you add it as an answer I will accept it

Comment: @Matthias: I found a duplicate, check out the answers.

Comment: Oki. Hopefully the title will direct some users towards the right answer.